# Mybatis log4j How print sql log in console?

Tags: java, log4j, mybatis

I want to print sql log in console. but it was failed when I tried it.
Help me out.

my log4.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.src.main.resources.mybatis.query=DEBUG, console
log4j.logger.src.main.resources.mybatis.query.updateSessionStatus=DEBUG, console
log4j.logger.query=TRACE
log4j.logger.mybatis.query.updateSessionStatus=TRACE
```

my xml files
src/main/resources/mybatis/Session.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--  <!DOCTYPE sqlMap PUBLIC "-//iBATIS.com//DTD SQL Map 2.0//EN" "http://www.ibatis.com/dtd/sql-map-2.dtd"> -->
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >
<mapper namespace="query">

<update id="updateSessionStatus" parameterType="java.lang.String">
        UPDATE TB_SSN SET
            <if test = "onOff == 'ON'">
            SSN_STS = "ON"
            </if>
            <if test = "onOff == 'OFF'">
            SSN_STS = "OF",
            SSN_EPD_TIME = #{time}#
            </if>
        WHERE SSN_KEY = #{sessionKey}#
</update>
</mapper>
```

Comment: No, I tried each of them once

Comment: Have you looked http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/logging.html ?

Answer (score 0):

`log4j.logger.query=DEBUG` should be closer to the truth. More generally `log4j.logger.mapper.namespace.value=DEBUG` Expected logger name is package name or class name. With `src.main.resources.mybatis` you try to provide some kind of file path but `src.main.resources` does not exist on runtime.

You may not need to add the appender at the end of the line: root logger already logs debug to stdout.
And the *console* appender name is not defined, name is stdout.